# What will be the best data type to store images and videos in oracle data base?

Tags: database, oracle

I'm using oracle data base and want to store images uploaded by the users of my product what will be the efficient way to  store multiple pictures in the oracle data base?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481841/text-images-files-in-oracle

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715544/how-do-i-store-tiff-files-in-oracle

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601375/is-it-possible-to-store-an-image-in-oracle-11g-express-edition

Comment: or, just use search http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=store+picture+in+oracle

Answer (score 0):

You may use BLOB for images. Please refer to below link which contains detailed procedure.

> http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_storing_insert_photo_pictures_tables.htm